# How to make only part of my layout (including partial views) invisible based off coordinates?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin

I have a layout that I only want parts of it to be invisible depending on coordinates that I provid it. This would mean that some of the views within my layout would be partially invisible (for example, if the coordinates only cover part of the view but not all of it). Is this possible? Any methods you’d suggest me taking a look into? Thanks!

Comment: What kind of variety of views are you dealing with? Just a bunch of text or image views or something more complex like a RecyclerView? If by invisible you mean completely transparent, what is behind the Views? Just some background color or something more complex? When you say 'coordinates you provide', are we only talking about rectangular parts of a View or is it more complex?

Comment: @ThomasLeyk The views are more complex! And I want that chunk of the layout to essentially disappear/be transparent, revealing whatever is underneath it (be it some other layout or more complex). For the coordinates, it would be a curved square shape that I want to make invisible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution would be to extend whatever layout you are using, override it's `drawChild()` method, and then applying a custom `canvas.clipPath()` before calling`super.drawChild()`. I added a quick prototype for this kind of solution below.

What the PartiallyTransparentLayout does:

- Prevent any child views, no matter their drawing code,
- from drawing inside the area that is specified by the given Path
- and instead, show whatever is behind the layout.

What it doesn't do:

- Remove the child views from the input framework. This means all input events are still dispatched as usual, even for completely invisible views.

This can certainly be classified as a hack type of solution, there is no guarantee that it will work in future versions of the framework. I am also not sure about the performance of this solution when working with a more complex view hierarchy. You should consider only invalidating the part of the layout that was affected by the change in the clipping path.

Let me know if I misunderstood the requirements you have.

EDIT: I just noticed that certain material animations will still be shown inside of the clipping path.

[image: Prototype screenshot]

### MainActivity.java

Only used for the OnClickListener

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener   {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        PartiallyTransparentLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.magic_layout);

        final int maxWidth = layout.getWidth();
        final int maxHeight = layout.getHeight();

        Path p = new Path();
        p.moveTo((float) (Math.random() * maxWidth), (float) (Math.random() * maxHeight));
        p.lineTo((float) (Math.random() * maxWidth), (float) (Math.random() * maxHeight));
        p.lineTo((float) (Math.random() * maxWidth), (float) (Math.random() * maxHeight));
        p.close();

        layout.setClipping(p);
    }
```

}

### PartiallyTransparentLayout.java

This is where all the magic happens

```
public class PartiallyTransparentLayout extends ConstraintLayout {
    private Path clipPath = null;

    public PartiallyTransparentLayout(Context c) {
        super(c);
    }

    public PartiallyTransparentLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public PartiallyTransparentLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    // Intercept the drawChild call and set a custom clipping for all following drawing operations
    @Override
    protected boolean drawChild(Canvas canvas, View child, long drawingTime) {
        // Our clipPath specifies the area we are NOT allowed to draw in, inversing the clipping
        // is different on higher Android versions.
        if (clipPath != null) {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                canvas.clipOutPath(clipPath);
            } else {
                canvas.clipPath(clipPath, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
            }
        }

        // Let the framework continue as if nothing happened.
        return super.drawChild(canvas, child, drawingTime);
    }

    // Specify the custom clipping
    public void setClipping(Path p) {
        clipPath = p;

        // Every time the clip changes, every view needs to redraw to account for it.
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

### activity_main.xml

Mostly just contains a bunch of random views for testing purposes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.transparent_viewgroup_test.PartiallyTransparentLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/magic_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.191"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.48" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="96dp"
    android:text="Button"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="76dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="76dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:src="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="148dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="148dp"
    android:src="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/switch1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switch1" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
    android:text="Switch"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="86dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />

</com.example.transparent_viewgroup_test.PartiallyTransparentLayout>
```

Comment: @ThomasLeky I really appreciate your detailed answer! I will take a closer look into this and I'll keep this post updated as well.

Comment: @ThomasLeky This worked great! Thanks. I also have a much better understanding of how onDraw() works as well after messing around with your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
view.setVisibility(INVISIBLE)
```

And if you want to change visibility of a group of views put them in a viewgroup and set the viewgroup's visibility to INVISIBLE.

Answer (score 0):

This is technically not possible unless you:

- Create your own custom Views
- Do some trickery

Typically, the easiest approach would be the trickery part, but this also depends on what you mean by invisible.

For example, a common way to make a part of a View invisible is simply to create a colored View with the same color as the Background of the Activity. Then you place that View ontop of the parts of the other views you want to be 'invisible'. The effect will be the same as if only parts of the View is visible and other parts are invisible.